# right way to retrieve query parameters in Spring Boot rest?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing REST api using Spring Boot. I've a controller which accepts POST requests.

> http://localhost:8085/carride/end-ride

In the above request i want to access the parameter `ride_transection_id` for finding particular transection object and also some other value as well.
So basically i have 3 way to do that.

**1.** i can use `@PathVariable`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/end-ride", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> endRide(@PathVariable("ride_transection_id") long ride_transection_id,@RequestBody 
SomeDTORequest someDTORequest ) {
//find transaction using path varibale 

}
```

**2.**i can use `@RequestParam`

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/end-ride", method = RequestMethod.POST
    public @ResponseBody item getitem(@RequestParam("ride_transection_id") 
    long ride_transection_id,@RequestBody SomeDTORequest someDTORequest ){

    //find transaction using RequestParam varibale 

    }
```

3. i can use DTO Object `SomeDTORequest` and accept  `ride_transection_id` into that with other value as well.

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/end-ride", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<?> endRide(@RequestBody SomeDTORequest someDTORequest ) {
   //find transaction using path someDTORequest .getID()
   ```

   }

i am little bit confuses.just want ask which is safest and right way to access the `ride_transection_id` ?

thanks

Comment: there is no one right answer to this. It depends on your requirement. What exactly do u mean by safest here?

Comment: I prefer to use @PathVariable("ride_transection_id") for this, cause it is the correct way to receive an object by id (my viewpoint). @RequestParams are more about configurations/additinal params to manipulate with data before/after fetching.

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of them but every way is designed for a certain use.

Path variable:
is used when you need to access an entity using a certain field for example i want to access an order and this order is defined by id so to access this order i need the following request `Get /order/{id}`

Request Parameter:
when you want to send a specific variable or flag for a certain method
for example `Get /orders?is_shipped=true`, so this will get all shipped orders or you may need orders at certain page `Get /orders?page=1`

Request body:
when you need to update the entity by the put or patch request as you will update the entity using the entity's json representation which can be send through the request body
for example `PUT /orders/{id}`
body: `{"title": "order_1"}`
then the order with id {id} will be updated with the new title

[Spring data rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

[See also](https://hellokoding.com/restful-api-example-with-spring-boot-spring-data-rest-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all these 3 methods are fine. But if you want to develop or design RESTful services with best practices, I strongly recommend you should provide the querying service with `@PathVariable` and **GET** method such as `GET /tickets/12`. Otherwise, to digest request body with `@RequestBody` annotation to retrieve querying criteria for **POST** method is the second suggestion.

Because **POST** method is usually to be used for creating something. And for querying something, both `@PathVariable` and `@RequestParam` annotations are suitable for **GET** method. More specifically, `@RequestParam` is often to be used in *Filtering*, *Sorting* and *Searching* results. For example:

- Filtering: `GET /tickets?state=open` - Here, state is a query parameter that implements a filter.
- Sorting: `GET /tickets?sort=-priority,created_at` - Retrieves a list of tickets in descending order of priority. Within a specific priority, older tickets are ordered first.
- Searching: `GET /tickets?state=closed&sort=-updated_at` - Retrieve recently closed tickets.

Please also refer to this article [Best Practices for Designing a Pragmatic RESTful API](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api).
Hope this helps you! :)